# What anime is this?

Tags: story-identification, anime

To summarize, i remember it being about a young girl, in the anime she was blonde, she lived in a small town by the water with a an older lady (either mom or sister), the young girl ended up befriending some homeless man. Towards the end you find out the young girl is ill, and I'm pretty sure in the last episode her hair was cut short and she was in a wheelchair. And ended up dying. I cannot find the anime to save my life, even when I type all of this in Google.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are any science fiction or fantasy elements present in this anime? If not, this question wouldn't be on-topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be asking about a science fiction or fantasy property.

Comment: Casey, could you include some information about the genre? Are there any other details you can remember, such as certain scenes?

Comment: See if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DelicateAndSickly/AnimeAndManga

Comment: I'm  going to guess that this might be "AIR" (2005), an anime based on a Key visual novel of the same name.   And yes, it could be considered SF.  The "homeless man" has the power to animate small objects, a gift inherited from his mother.  He is homeless in the sense that he is a perpetual traveler searching the world for a girl with wings that his mother spent her life searching for.  The anime covers his time in a seaside village where he meets a girl, Misuzu, who becomes increasingly weak and by the final episode is in a wheelchair.    (continued in next comment)

Comment: A story-within-the-story makes clear that the main characters are reincarnations of figures who played a part in complicated events a thousand years earlier, a saga of magic and betrayal.  A central figure of the thousand years past drama was a winged woman with great magical power. No room here for a proper excerpt or longer summary. Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Air_episodes

Comment: Thank you Ethan!!!! Omg I've spent years trying to find it  you're the best. Also didn't remember the anime being so deep, I'll be rewatching it now with all of that in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: @Casey: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

This is *AIR* (Kyoto Animation 2005), based on a Key visual novel of the same name.

- The "homeless man" is Yukito, an itinerant performer (sort of a one-man travelling show) with the ability to animate small objects that he uses to make a small puppet dance. He is searching for a "girl in the sky". Both the search and the special ability were inherited through his mother.
- The girl in a seaside village is Misuzu. She lives with her aunt(?) [I don't recall their exact connection]. Misuzu acts younger than her apparent age and has episodes of weakness that become increasingly severe over the course of the story. She is in a wheelchair by the end.
- There are several side stories, alternate routes through the original visual novel, involving other girls in the same seaside village.
- A story-within-the-story makes clear that the main characters are reincarnations of figures who played a part in complicated events a thousand years earlier, a saga of magic and betrayal. A central figure of the thousand years past drama was a winged woman with great magical power.  It's complicated, too much so to present clearly in the limited number of episodes used in the anime.

It has a very catchy opening theme *Tori no Uta* ("song of a bird") that would probably twig your memory immediately: